# Derive Regresion Coefficint Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

in matrix notation linear model can be written as 
$$y=\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{b} $$
where 
$$\mathbf{x'}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_1 &x_2 &\dots & x_n \end{bmatrix} $$
and 
$$\mathbf{b} =\begin{bmatrix} b_0 \\ b_1 \\ b_2  \\ \vdots  \\ b_n \end{bmatrix} $$
The $ \mathbf{x} $ data matrix is 
$$ \mathbf{X_d} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_{11} &\dots& x_{1n}
                             \\  \vdots & \vdots & &\vdots
                              \\ 1 & x_{m1} &\dots& x_{mn}  \end{bmatrix} $$
in the case $m>n$ the least square problem is over determined

the data $y$ matrix is 
$$\mathbb{y_d '}=\begin{bmatrix}d_{y1} & \dots& d_{yn} \end{bmatrix} $$

the regression coefficient vector $\mathbf{b}$ can be found my minimizing SSE
$$ SSE= \|y_d-\mathbf{X}b \|^2$$

Derive that $$ \mathbf{b=(X_d' X_d)^{-1} X_d y_d}$$

by taking partial derivative of SSE with respecta to $b_i$ where $i \in \{1, \dots,n \}$ will lead to n linear equations

---

Not to sure how to start besides mult out $Xb$ and turn into summation notation then somehow translate it to $b$ in the matrix notation but that seems wrong in this case.

Comment: P.S: you have a mistake of transposition in the last $\pmb{b}$ expression

Comment: ok got it on last X_d has to be transpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(\pmb{b}) = \Vert \pmb{y} - \pmb{X}\pmb{b} \Vert^2$$
Expand you get
$$f(\pmb{b}) = \Vert \pmb{y} \Vert^2 - \pmb{y}^T\pmb{X}\pmb{b} - \pmb{b}^T\pmb{X}^T\pmb{y}+  \pmb{b}^T \pmb{X}^T \pmb{X} \pmb{b}$$
Derive and set to zero
$$\frac{\partial f(\pmb{b}) }{\partial \pmb{b}} = - 2\pmb{X}^T\pmb{y}+2\pmb{X}^T \pmb{X} \pmb{b} = \pmb{0}$$
which gives
$$\pmb{\hat{b}}= (\pmb{X}^T \pmb{X})^{-1}\pmb{X}^T\pmb{y}$$